# How to Print Angular Dashboard Content

Tags: html, angular, angularjs, sass, angular-material

Im currently in the process of creating a legal document automation program for the company i work for, however i have run into one issue on possibly one the last step of completing this web app.

I am using the default angular Dashboard layout and set-up, as you can see below.

[image: Dashboard Example]

The document in the dashboard scrolls a little as it is a full document, however it only prints one page worth of the scrollable content. as shown below.
[image: printing example]

I can show code if any one thinks it will help however in terms of printing using angular and components i haven't found anything yet, so it's all based around window.print() currently with a lot of CSS changes to get it to look right.

I will however show the css code here(its a bit overkill with me trying to figure out how to accomplish this):

```
@media print{
.documentView{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible !important;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}}
```

if anyone has done something like this before or has any tips regarding this, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this css property :
[https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside[break-inside][1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside%5Bbreak-inside%5D%5B1%5D)

Comment: no luck on that one sadly